# How can I read a file and calculate values with data in strings?

Tags: python-3.x

Let me explain what I mean: I have gotten data from nine pictures, including r,g,b values and brightness, calculated the averages for each picture, and then written those values for each onto a .txt file (in Notepad) in a string for each picture. I am now now trying to take any two strings from that file and calculate differences in the values through a difference formula (difference = val.1 - val. 2 / val.2). What I cannot figure out is how to read the .txt file and use two different strings for calculations. I would greatly appreciate any tips or help.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from graphics import *


def loadImage(image):
   totalBrightness = 0
   totalR = 0
   totalG = 0
   totalB = 0
   win = GraphWin("Picture", 400, 500)
   testImage = Image(Point(200,250), image)
   testImage.draw(win)
   throwAway = win.getMouse()
   theWidth = testImage.getWidth()
   theHeight = testImage.getHeight()
   for i in range(0,theWidth):
      for j in range(0,theHeight):
          r,g,b = testImage.getPixel(i,j)
          brightness = int(round(0.299*r + 0.587*g + 0.114*b))
          totalR = totalR + r
          totalG = totalG + g
          totalB = totalB + b
          totalBrightness = totalBrightness + brightness
    return (image, totalBrightness, totalR, totalG, totalB)


def ImageAnalysis():
   infile = open("Picture_Features.txt","a+") #cousin told me 'a+' work here if that's important
   print(loadImage("mystery1.GIF"), file = infile)
   print(loadImage("mystery2.GIF"), file = infile)
   print(loadImage("mystery3.GIF"), file = infile)
```

Comment: So you have 3 lines of text in your file - 3 tuples. The difference formula only works for 2 values. Do you want to do it for all possible combinations of tuples?

Comment: No, I was aiming to just do it for each of the mystery files in order to test those.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the method is fairly straightforward:

1. Read file by line and store as list of lines (string)
2. Convert all strings in list to a list/tuple
3. Take 2 entries in the list and use difference formula

Should look something like this:

```
f = open("Picture_Features.txt", 'r')
l = f.readlines()
f.close()

# Convert string to list with split
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = l[i][1:-1].split(', ')

# Let's take the first 2 entries (not the image string in the front)
e1, e2 = map(int, l[0][1:]), map(int, l[1][1:])
diff_formula = lambda x1, x2: (x1 - x2) / x2
result = map(diff_formula, e1, e2)
```